# Doxygen not handling conditional compilation

Tags: doxygen

This is with Doxygen built from git head.

```
doxygen -v
1.11.0 (db523de7141a3f138c4f0a723249fd1f8816a54a)
```

I'm trying to use Doxygen on a project that I'm working on. In particular I want to see the callgraph for a few member functions. The project compiles the set of files twice, once for internal use in the main executable and also a second time to generate a shared lib (for a different exe). That second build uses a macro to limit what goes into the shared lib. To reflect that I want to run Doxygen twice, once without the macro and once with.

The code looks something like this

```
int Class::func()
{
#ifndef SHARED_LIB
   // one function call
#endif
   // common code, 4 calls
#ifndef SHARED_LIB
   // 11 calls for main exe
#else
   // 1 call for shared lib
#endif
}
```

For the first run I have

`ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES`

and then the second run I also add

`PREDEFINED             = SHARED_LIB`

It looks like the first ifndef is being handled correctly.

However the second ifndef seems to have no effect. Both branches of the ifndef get added to the callgraph.

Is this a Doxygen bug?

I'll try to make a small reproducer.

Comment: You write "This is with Doxygen built from git head." as this is a moving target,, please specify the full version i.e. the result from `doxygen -v`. You write "Both branches of the ifndef get added to the callgraph.", this is a known issue in doxygen as the determination of the call graphs depends on the lexer that shows the code and for that pass the files are not preprocessed.